# How to use python decimal modules to avoid floating arithmetic Issues

Tags: python

I tried `decimal` modules to avoid floating arithmetic issues to calculate `4 - 3.2`

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> a = D(4)
>>> b = D(3.2)
>>> c = a - b
>>> c
Decimal('0.7999999999999998223643160600')
```

Also i tried addition `0.1 + 0.2`

```
>>> a = D(0.1)
>>> b = D(0.2)
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
Decimal('0.3000000000000000166533453694')
```

So what method should i use to get a accurate answer?

Comment: You need to start with accurate decimals - e.g. `b = D('3.2')`. If you start with floats, you've already lost precision.

Comment: there is no float values are used

Comment: Yes, there is - you are creating a float with the literal `3.2` and passing *that* to `Decimal`. In my comment, by contrast, I'm passing **a string**.

Comment: so, can i use that decimal values directly for calculations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Why don't you read through https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html and see where you get to?